# Fullcalendar with Vue 3 support

Tags: typescript, vue.js, fullcalendar, vuejs3

I installed the `fullcalendar` library to my Vue 3 project but when I serve the application, I get a warning in my terminal that says:

> export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

This crashes the app with the same error when I open the browser. I tried creating the shim.d.ts with the required content but this doesn't still solve the problem. Is there any workaround for this or is this library not supported with Vue 3?

Comment: For the moment you can't. You must wait for fullCalendar migration in Vue 3. Or you can still in Vue 2 using the composition api but personally I don't like this option.

Comment: You can also use the fullCalendar in full vanilla JS and make your own plugin system for Vue 3.

Answer (score 3):

The way I managed to get in fullcalendar in Vue3 is to initialize it in ES6. I guess you can make this more dynamic, but see below the basic code which should get it working, using ref in the setup and the onMounted lifecycle hook. This needs to be further customized and filled with events. I guess it could also be improved, still can be a good starting point.

```
<template>
        <div class="card" ref="cal"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref,defineComponent, onMounted} from 'vue';
import {Calendar} from '@fullcalendar/core'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';

export default defineComponent({
name:'myCalendar',
setup(){
    const cal = ref(null);
    
    onMounted(()=>{
        const Tcalendar = new Calendar(cal.value, {
        plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
         headerToolbar: {
         left: 'prev,next today',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
             }
        });
        Tcalendar.render();
    })
    return {
        cal,
        
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: cdn links or via webpack? if via cdn pls share the full example.. it we be really helpful.

Comment: its via webpack

Comment: need cdn support.. not using webpack

Answer (score 0):

I can get primevue's fullcalendar component working in a vue 3 app, inside of their diamond template, though I haven't done much with it.

There is a dependency on @fullcalendar/core, but not on @fullcalendar/vue